# Add logos to the right and left of the title of my poster (tikzposter)

Tags: titles, tikzposter, logos

I want to add logos to the top corners of my poster.
This is what I have:

```
\documentclass[20pt,margin=1.5in,innermargin=-5in,blockverticalspace=-0.1in]{tikzposter}
\geometry{paperwidth=45in,paperheight=36in}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric]{biblatex}
\usepackage{uwtheme}
\usepackage{mwe} % for placeholder images
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{conj}[thm]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem*{example}{Example}
%\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}
%\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{rem}[thm]{Remark}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\newtheorem{case}{Case}
\newtheorem{subcase}{Subcase}
\numberwithin{subcase}{case}
\addbibresource{refs.bib}
% set theme parameters
\tikzposterlatexaffectionproofoff
\usetheme{UWTheme}
\usecolorstyle{UWStyle}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \title{\textbf{Quantum Math}}   
    \author{\textsuperscript{1}Joshua R.~Palmer \& 
    \textsuperscript{2}Gabriel Taylor}    
    \institute{\textsuperscript{1}The University of Texas Rio Grande Valley 
               \& \textsuperscript{2}University of Wisconsin - Madison} 
  \titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{coe.jpg}}

\begin{document}   
\maketitle
\centering
\begin{columns}
    \column{0.34}
```

This is what I want:
[image]

Comment: As this is only about the title, I suppose an example doesn't need any more content, so I'd suggest replacing `\centering \begin{columns}     \column{0.34}` in your example with `\end{document}`. That said though, `uwtheme` is not a standard theme for `tikzposter`, can you add a link to where it can be downloaded? (Your example would also be better if it didn't include references to other files we don't have, such as `refs.bib` -- not needed -- or `coe.jpg` -- replace with `example-image`.)

Answer (score 2):

A perhaps slightly hackish method, that will work regardless of theme, but that requires a bit of trial and error, is to simply use a couple of `\node`s to place the images. A `tikzposter` is just one big `tikzpicture`, and the coordinates `bottomleft` and `topright` are defined by the class, so you can do something like this:

```
\documentclass[a2paper]{tikzposter}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}   
\maketitle
\node [below right=4cm and 2cm] at (bottomleft |- topright) {\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}};
\node [below left=4cm and 2cm] at (topright) {\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-b}};
\end{document}
```

The distances in e.g. `below right=4cm and 2cm` has to be modified depending on the papersize used, the position of the title, and what you like yourself. The first length is the vertical distance, the second the horizontal.

[image]